# How to write data from datagridview to XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I have added a lot of blank lines to the datagridview and I want to write the data to xml. I've done a few little researches, but I'm glad that you did not do it the way I wanted to.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "SD";
dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
dt.WriteXml("SD.xml");
```

it's not working or i couldn't run it.

Its error message:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I think you xml file path is not correct.

Comment: nope, i changed xml file path but i don import data from datagridview

Comment: I enter the data in the DataGridView but I can not read it, so I can not write to XML.

Comment: it's error message:System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: It's very likely that your `dt` is coming back `null` in `dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;`, therefore throwing `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Make sure your `dataGridView1.DataSource` can actually be cast `as DataTable`

Comment: You need `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` at first. Then if somewhere you try to `(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).WriteXml(...)`, then it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely that your `dt` is coming back `null` in `dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;`, therefore throwing `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Make sure your `dataGridView1.DataSource` can actually be cast `as DataTable`

Here's a full snippet.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewToXML_47696565
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        DataTable dgvdt = new DataTable();
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        Button btn = new Button();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitOurStuff();
        }

        private void InitOurStuff()
        {
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
            dgv.DataSource = dgvdt;
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

            dgvdt.TableName = "SD";
            dgvdt.Columns.Add();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgvdt.Rows.Add($"row {i}");
            }

            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.Location = new Point(5, dgv.Location.Y + dgv.Height + 5);
            btn.Text = "Click me";
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;

        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgvdt.WriteXml(@"c:\temp\mydtxml.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's another snippet where my DataSource is not already a DataTable.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewToXML_47696565
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        BindingList<dgventry> dgvdata = new BindingList<dgventry>();
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        Button btn = new Button();


        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initOurStuff();
        }

        private void initOurStuff()
        {
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            dgv.DataSource = dgvdata;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgvdata.Add(new dgventry { col1 = $"col1 row{i}", col2 = $"col2 row{i}", col3 = $"col3 row{i}" });
            }

            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.Location = new Point(5, dgv.Location.Y + dgv.Height + 5);
            btn.Text = "Click me";
            btn.Click += Btn_Click; ;
        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            /*The DataSource connected to the DGV is not already a DataTable,
             so I'll traverse the DataGridView and create my own DataTable out of it*/
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();//create the data table
            dt.TableName = "SD";//give it a name
            //create the appropriate number of columns
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText);
            }

            //loop through each row of the DataGridView
            foreach (DataGridViewRow currentRow in dgv.Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int runningCount = 0;
                //loop trough each column of the row
                foreach (DataGridViewCell item in currentRow.Cells)
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][runningCount] = item.FormattedValue;
                    runningCount++;
                }
            }

            if (dt != null)
            {
                dt.WriteXml(@"c:\temp\mynewxml.xml");
            }

        }
    }


    public class dgventry
    {
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public string col3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's another snippet. In this one, the DataGridView starts empty. The user has to manually enter data into it.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewToXML_47696565
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {

        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        Button btn = new Button();

        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initOurStuff();
        }

        private void initOurStuff()
        {
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewColumn newcol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                newcol.Name = $"col{i}";
                dgv.Columns.Add(newcol);
            }

            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.Location = new Point(5, dgv.Location.Y + dgv.Height + 5);
            btn.Text = "Click me";
            btn.Click += Btn_Click; ;
        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();//create the data table
            dt.TableName = "SD";//give it a name
            //create the appropriate number of columns
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText);
            }

            //loop through each row of the DataGridView
            foreach (DataGridViewRow currentRow in dgv.Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int runningCount = 0;
                //loop trough each column of the row
                foreach (DataGridViewCell item in currentRow.Cells)
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][runningCount] = item.FormattedValue;
                    runningCount++;
                }
            }

            if (dt != null)
            {
                dt.WriteXml(@"c:\temp\mynewxml.xml");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My friend thanks for help but i hava a datagridview already this only add row in any empty space and this did not work for me it's detail: i have datagridview with 10 columns and i can add blank rows on it. and I can enter data in these blank rows. but i can not read data from this datagridview. I want to read data from datagridview write to XML file do u understand me?

Comment: These are two snippets that demonstrate how to create the Datagridview, populate it, as well as how to export it to XML in 2 different manners. I strongly believe the answer to your problem lies in there. You are not showing us how you are populating the DataGridView so we have to make certain assumptions when answering you.

Comment: @DavidHayter, added a third snippet.